# leapp does not want to upgrade Oracle Linux from 7.9 to 8.x

Tags: package-management, oracle-linux

I migrated from CentOS 7.9 to Oracle linux 7.9, and now I want to upgrade from 7.9 to 8 with leapp application. It is a bare metal installation running apache, PHP, MySQL, sendmail. Nothing really special, and no wierd or exotic packages. I had to uninstall sysvinit-tools, which uninstalled sendmail, and some other stuff, because leapp complained about it. I can install them again when upgrade will be finished.

Preupgrade check always succeeds. It is the upgrade that fails ultimately.

Upgrade process still reports errors and halts. It says I should uninstall leapp, too. Without leapp, I cannot upgrade. I tried to un/reinstall leapp, but it does not help. I also checked for packages rpcsvc-proto-devel libnsl2-devel rpcgen, which are metioned in the error message. They are not installed. I tried to install them to OL 7.9, but they are not available?

System is updated with the latest updates. Does anybody have an idea, how can I proceed?

This is the error output of an upgrade:

```
STDERR:
Warning: Packages marked by Leapp for install not found in repositories metadata: rpcsvc-proto-devel libnsl2-devel rpcgen
Warning: Packages marked by Leapp for upgrade not found in repositories metadata: python2-leapp leapp-upgrade-el7toel8 leapp
RPM: warning: Generating 6 missing index(es), please wait...
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py from install of python2-six-1.11.0-6.module+el8.4.0+20050+79c7b4ee.noarch conflicts with file from package python-six-1.9.0-2.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.pyc from install of python2-six-1.11.0-6.module+el8.4.0+20050+79c7b4ee.noarch conflicts with file from package python-six-1.9.0-2.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.pyo from install of python2-six-1.11.0-6.module+el8.4.0+20050+79c7b4ee.noarch conflicts with file from package python-six-1.9.0-2.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py from install of python2-cairo-1.16.3-6.module+el8+5156+a8abff8b.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pycairo-1.8.10-8.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cairo/__init__.pyc from install of python2-cairo-1.16.3-6.module+el8+5156+a8abff8b.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pycairo-1.8.10-8.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cairo/__init__.pyo from install of python2-cairo-1.16.3-6.module+el8+5156+a8abff8b.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pycairo-1.8.10-8.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.so from install of python2-cairo-1.16.3-6.module+el8+5156+a8abff8b.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pycairo-1.8.10-8.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/__init__.pyc from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/__init__.pyo from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/codec.pyc from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/codec.pyo from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/compat.pyc from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/compat.pyo from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/core.py from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/core.pyc from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/core.pyo from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/idnadata.pyc from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/idnadata.pyo from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/intranges.pyc from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/intranges.pyo from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/uts46data.pyc from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/idna/uts46data.pyo from install of python2-idna-2.5-7.module+el8.3.0+7833+4aaf98ce.noarch conflicts with file from package python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
  file /usr/bin/pyinotify from install of python3-inotify-0.9.6-13.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python-inotify-0.9.4-4.el7.noarch
```

---

**Addition**: I have found out that rpcgen package is in Code Ready Builder repository. Therefore, repository has to be added manually to the leapp command with `--enablerepo 'ol8_codeready_builder'`.

That removes the first warning, but does not solve the problem with leapp packages.

Comment: Found this https://access.redhat.com/discussions/6259931. Will report about success.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the packages `python-six`, `pycairo`, and `python-idna` were installed together with certbot from CentOS EPEL. That was the reason why Oracle Linux did not find upgrade candidates and aborted the upgrade every time. The solution was to reinstall those packages:

```
yum reinstall python-six pycairo python-idna
```

The next upgrade attempt reported some more packages which were reinstalled, too.

```
yum reinstall python-ipaddress python-backports python-backports-ssl_match_hostname
```

After that the upgrade went through that stage. Now, efibootmgr reports an error, because I believe I have buggy UEFI BIOS, but that is another topic. :(